# ActiveJDBC and Dropwizard integration

Tags: java, dropwizard, activejdbc

Is it possible to use ActiveJDBC as my ORM instead of Hibernate that Dropwizard provides. How do I set it up if it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with Dropwizard, but after looking at their docs, I see absolutely no reason why ActiveJDBC would not work. They use migrations system Liquibase, which I too used for a few ActiveJDBC projects. Dropwizard seems a decent framework for building services, but we have been using ActiveWeb: http://javalite.io/activeweb for all backend JSON/XML/Rest web services.

Back to Dropwizard: since they use Maven as a build tool, all you have to do to bring ActiveJDBC, is to configure the instrumentation plugin in pom: http://javalite.io/instrumentation
and add a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
    <artifactId>activejdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

ActiveJDBC is a general purpose ORM, and will work with any Java framework.

cheers.